# How to delete entity from google App engine Datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I created an entity in the Google App Engine datastore.

How can I remove this entity?

Answer (score 4):

You haven't specified which API you're using.

In Python it's [like so](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/creatinggettinganddeletingdata.html#Deleting_an_Entity):

```
db.delete(modelId)
```

In Java it should be [like](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/creatinggettinganddeletingdata.html#Deleting_an_Object) (I haven't tested this):

```
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();

MyModel entity = pm.getObjectById(MyModel.class, modelId);
pm.deletePersistent(entity);

pm.close();
```

Comment: The Python example is incorrect - 'key' is a reserved field name, so can't be used as a property. It should either be filtering on another property, or using MyModel.get to get by key.  In the former case, a batch delete such as db.delete(MyModel.all().fetch(500)) is _much_ more efficient.

Comment: The Java example shows how to remove a single Object from an Entity (or Kind in google talk) using JDO, not how to remove an Entity, in fact it gets a specific Object by id (modelId) and then deletes it. Anyway to delete a Kind, you've to delete all data in it.

Answer (score 3):

In python if you know the key it really simple:

```
db.delete(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have an endpoint:

```
Somethingendpoint endpoint = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(endpointBuilder).build();
```

And then:

```
endpoint.remove<ModelName>(long ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can also try something like the following (In Python pseudo-code):

```
class MyClass(ndb.Model):
    myString = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=false)

def deleteAllEntities():
    entities = MyClass.query()
    for entity in entities:
        entity.key.delete()
```

Admittedly there are better ways to do bulk deletion, but this is a way you can use if you are having trouble.

More info here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities#Python_Deleting_an_entity